# move files from onedrive to document lib

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, onedrive-for-business, move

I would like to move some files and folders from Onedrive and to a document library in teamsite.
What are my options?
I tried loking at the free sharepoint migration tool but didn't have a source for Onedrive.
Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you can use the OOTB option copy or move to move the files from onedrive to other Sharepoint sites. their is one limitation that move /copy  up to 500 MB of files and folders at a time.

[For Move:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-files-and-folders-between-onedrive-and-sharepoint-5916f90d-f58a-4bf9-b135-10853f516d0b)

[image]

[For Copy:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-files-and-folders-between-onedrive-and-sharepoint-sites-67a6323e-7fd4-4254-99a8-35613492a82f)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that and I discovered that too. The issue I have is that it's quite a deep nested folder and not sure the size of the files in them.Do you know of the free SharePoint migration tool will move files from Onedrive?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any free but you can try sharegate or meta logix as they offer free trials.i think that may help.

Comment: I waa referring to this one https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2018/05/10/the-microsoft-sharepoint-migration-tool-v2-is-now-generally-available/